# Disable submit when no input text or dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, sharepoint-online

Code below works fine with one textbox input 'departname'. However, i require all input fields to have data and the 'ACFTREG' dropdown (populated from a Sharepoint list) has a selection that isnt the default value 'select'. Please note that this code will be displayed in a CEWP of Sharepoint Online, hence form tags arent allowed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var checkField;
  checkField = $("input#departname").val().length;
  var enableDisableButton = function() {
    if (checkField > 0) {
      $('#btnUploadFiles').removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
      $('#btnUploadFiles').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
  }
  enableDisableButton();
  $('input#departname').keyup(function() {
    checkField = $("input#departname").val().length;
    enableDisableButton();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Select File: <input type="File" id="inputTypeFiles" required><br />
Departname: <input id="departname" type="textbox" required><br />
Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" autocomplete="off" name="hidden" required><br />
Filename: <input id="filename" type="textbox" required><br />
ACFTREG:
<select id="ACFTREG" class="select" required>
  <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select</option><br />
  <input type="submit" id="btnUploadFiles" value="Upload" />
</select>
```

Comment: You mean you want to enable the upload button  once you got all the values including the select option right? or something else I'm not sure about your question

Comment: Yes, youre right. Enable upload button when all inputs have values including the select.

Comment: Ok you got the answer I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you'd use the `form.validate` method for this. But as you point out, in Sharepoint CEWP it's not possible to use a form element because the page it's rendered in already has a form element surrounding it. And nested form elements don't work well. ([source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/content-editor-web-part-c1350ff6-934c-4c2e-8e53-1ec3b548a0dc?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us))

Rather then just checking for the value, you could check each input/select field for validity. This has benefits if you would add additional [built in HTML form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#using_built-in_form_validation) to it (`required`, `minlength`, `maxlength`, etc.). Since you're using the `required` attribute, the form is not valid until you add a value.

The event to handle the validation of the fields can be done with the [blur event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event) on each input. Meaning that the form validation will trigger when a user clicks out of the input element.

```js
function checkAllFields(fields) {
  return $.map(fields, function(field) {
    return field.checkValidity();
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var fields = document.querySelectorAll('input,select');
  var submitButton = document.getElementById('btnUploadFiles');

  $(fields).each(function(_, field) {
    field.addEventListener('blur', function() {
      var allFieldsValid = checkAllFields(fields).every(function(value) { return value });
      if (allFieldsValid) {
        $(submitButton).prop('disabled', false);
      } else {
        $(submitButton).prop('disabled', true);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Select File: <input type="File" id="inputTypeFiles" required><br />
Departname: <input id="departname" type="textbox" required><br />
Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" autocomplete="off" name="hidden" required><br />
Filename: <input id="filename" type="textbox" required><br />
ACFTREG:
<select id="ACFTREG" class="select" required>
  <option hidden="hidden" value="" selected="selected" disabled>Select</option>
  <option value="foo">Foo</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" id="btnUploadFiles" value="Upload" disabled />
```

Notes:

- Note that the input type submit should be outside of the select element.
- You wouldn't necessarily have to use jQuery for this. This can also be done with ES6. But since the question does not state which ES version is used, I answered with the jQuery example.
- The underscore `_` in the `$.each` [function](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) is to skip the index. You could omit the two arguments and use `this` instead, but it's nice to be specific about the object you're using there. Which is 'field'.

Comment: Working to recognize all input fields. However the dropdown select tag isnt being validated for a selection. I guess the first option Select is taken as a valid entry. Kindly assist.

Comment: Got it, updated the answer to also include  the select. Made the 'fields' var use querySelectorAll to do this. And added an option in the select so the behavior can be tested. Also note the "hidden" in the first option, that removes it visually from the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check all the input fields when the button is clicked instead of trying to enable it once all are filled.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#btnUploadFiles").click(function() {

    if ($("#departname").val() && $("#datepicker").val() && 
          $("#filename").val() && $("#ACFTREG").val() && 
          $("#inputTypeFiles").val()) {
      console.log("Every field has input");
    }else{
      console.log("Error: All fields are required.");  
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Select File: <input type="File" id="inputTypeFiles" required><br /> Departname: <input id="departname" type="textbox" required><br /> Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" autocomplete="off" name="hidden" required><br /> Filename: <input id="filename"
  type="textbox" required><br /> ACFTREG:
<select id="ACFTREG" class="select" required>
  <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select</option><br />
  <option selected="Option1">Option1</option><br />
  <input type="submit" id="btnUploadFiles" value="Upload" />
</select>
```